# RVIZ Laser Scan Display

Tags: rviz, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I want to display a laser scan data I have, file Mapping1.bag from a ROS tutorial(http://wiki.ros.org/laser_pipeline/Tutorials/IntroductionToWorkingWithLaserScannerData).
When I run the bag file and try to display it on RVIZ with the right topic, I am having an error message :

"Transform [sender=unknown_publisher]
For frame [base_laser_link]: Fixed Frame [map] does not exist"

LaserScan status is on ERROR and nothing is displayed.

Any idea about this problem ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/310895/rviz-laser-scan-display/) by [karl](https://answers.ros.org/users/39063/karl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2018-12-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2018-12-17**:
This means RVIZ cannot take the base_link_laser frame onto the map frame. Could you update your post with a link to the tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

RVIZ is not showing the laser scan because the 'fixed frame' is set to map. The laser scan has a different coordinate frame and there is no known transformation between them.

To fix this you need to go to the world section in the top left of the RVIZ window and change the fixed frame to base_link_laser so that RVIZ is viewing in the laser's own coordinate frame, then this will start working.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karl](https://answers.ros.org/users/39063/karl/) on 2018-12-18**:
Thanks Pete, you were right but the fixed frame has to be : "base_laser_link" and not "base_link_laser" eheh :D